# Is there a list of all the StackOverflow Android tags?

Tags: discussion, android

I see that if I enter "Android-[any letter]" into the Tags edit box below, there are untold number of Android subtags (there's got to be about 100). Is there a list (page) somewhere that lists all of these in one place?

Comment: In Stack Exchange there aren't sub tags; those are tags that start with "android-" but that doesn't make them sub tags, as the concept doesn't exist on Stack Exchange.

Comment: @kiamlaluno: Maybe I'm obscuring the issue, but while there are no such things as hierarchical tags, there is something *similar* called a tag synonym.

Comment: Tag synonyms are on the same level, not on different levels. It is like when you say that an English word is a synonym of another one: It means that in some cases a word can be replaced from its synonym, not that a word is more important than its synonym.

Answer (score 6):

[SO Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags)

Search for 'android' and you'll get the list.

Answer (score 6):

There are exactly 50 tags:

```
android
android-layout
android-emulator
android-widget
android-ndk
android-manifest
android-listview
android-intent
android-market
android-webview
android-fragments
android-camera
android-service
android-c2dm
android-preferences
android-animation
android-sdk-2.2
android-tabhost
android-edittext
android-contacts
android-softkeyboard
android-ui
android-imageview
android-xml
android-sdcard
android-canvas
android-gallery
android-wifi
android-maps
android-asynctask
android-sdk-2.1
android-images
basic4android
android-2.2
android-contentprovider
android-textview
android-custom-view
android-source
android-ksoap2
android-viewpager
android-sensors
android-mediaplayer
android-device
android-browser
android-sdk-2.3
android-view
android-video-player
android-logcat
android-gridview
android-library
```

Comment: Thanks mate was looking for them.. since past 45 mins

Answer (score 2):

According to [the query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/s/2259/tags-starting-with-android) I just wrote on Data Explorer, there are 161 tags starting with `android`. You can see the full list if you view the query. Note that this is based on a snapshot of Stack Overflow from 13 Nov 2011, so it may be slightly outdated.

Comment: Probably includes tags that were subsequently consolidated, synonymized, or deleted due to lack of use

Comment: @Robert Good point. A lot can happen in a month on Stack Overflow.